# Question about Ordering Promises from Block Event Listeners

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethers.js

I am trying to figure out why block number data is not being returned sequentially. If I just print the block number within the event listener it provides block numbers sequentially, but right when I try to pull block information from that block number and chain with a "then" method it seems to delay the result enough to unorder the console logs. This is probably the result of me not fully understanding the event loop. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var ethers = require('ethers')
var dotenv = require('dotenv').config({path: '.env'})
var  provider =  new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.infura_polygon_https)

provider.on('block', (blockNumber) => {
    Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => provider.getBlock(blockNumber))
        .then((message) => console.log(blockNumber + ': ' + message.transactions.length ))
})
```

[console log results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkLS6.png)

Comment: Why are you starting your promise chain with `Promise.resolve()`?

Comment: That's a good point doesn't seem necessary. Doesn't seem to change the output.

Comment: If `block` events occur fast enough, and `provider.getBlock` of an earlier block takes longer than that of an earlier block, the logs will be out of order. I don't see what this has to do with the understanding of the event loop, or even with promises (callbacks would have the same behaviour), it's just basic independent asynchronous processes.

Comment: I'm sure you're right, but how do I force the script to block the program until the block information is returned?

Comment: You don't ever want to *block* the program :-) You want to delay the logging of the transaction count until all previous transaction counts have been logged. You can do that by queuing the promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to delay the logging of the transaction count until all previous transaction counts have been logged. You can do that by building a queue of the promises for these actions:

```
let queue = Promise.resolve()
provider.on('block', blockNumber => {
    queue = queue.then(() =>
        provider.getBlock(blockNumber)
    ).then(message => {
        console.log(blockNumber + ': ' + message.transactions.length)
    })
})
```

However, this is inefficient since all the `getBlock` calls must happen in sequence, and it doesn't handle errors properly (possibly breaking the entire chain). Better fetch each block already while still waiting for the previous logs being completed:

```
let queue = Promise.resolve()
provider.on('block', blockNumber => {
    queue = Promise.all([
        queue,
        provider.getBlock(blockNumber)
    ]).then(([, message] => {
        console.log(blockNumber + ': ' + message.transactions.length)
    }, err => {
        console.error(err.message)
    })
})
```

Comment: this works perfectly. thank you for the help on this. are you using the promise.all because you want to get the results of the queue and the new promise for proper error handling?

Comment: Because I want to wait for both the queue (i.e. the previous log) as well as for the block. The error handling is achieved through the second `.then()` argument